# Getting duplicate key error on CLUSTER_SYNC table when user loads first page

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have a Worklight app with a desktopbrowser environment setup (amongst a couple others environments). If the user goes to the app, logs in, logs out, then refreshes the browser page they often get the following error message:

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.
Logged Exception: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.DuplicateKeyException: One or more values in 
the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE 
statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index 
identified by "1" constrains table "lrwklct1.CLUSTER_SYNC" from having duplicate 
values for the index key.. SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, DRIVER=4.15.100
```

If the user refreshes the page a couple times they will eventually get the login page of the app again. Or if the user clears cookies then the error goes away.

Worklight 6.1 is running in a WAS 8.0.0.6 environment in a cluster with 2 nodes in the cluster. The underlying database is DB2.

This happens regardless of browser.

Thoughts?

Comment: Worklight version? Also try w/out d2 (use the default db) and see if it happens still or not.

Comment: Edited question. Worklight version is 6.1. When you say without d2, are you meaning not using DB2 but use the bundled embedded database?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Meant to write "db2".

Comment: In further investigation, the error was only occurring on a single node of the cluster. We rebooted that node of the cluster and now the problem no longer occurs. I don't think that's a fix of the root cause, but at least it's not happening any more.

Comment: I'd put that as an answer than a comment, as well as verify that you are running 6.1.0.1, the latest 6.1 fix pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In further investigation, the error was only occurring on a single node of the cluster. We rebooted that node of the cluster and now the problem no longer occurs. I don't think that's a fix of the root cause, but at least it's not happening any more.